# How to run my code asynchronously when using asyncio queue.put() and queue.get() as part of task are gone?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I am writing a code to simulate getting data from a website which takes 3-5seconds with multiple selenium drivers. I intend that it will get the batch data and go through the `retrieve()` function asynchronously to speed up the process. I am trying to use the asyncio queue to achieve this by using `queue.put()` and `queue.get()`. The result is incorrect part of the `current_value` 11 to 15 are somehow disappeared as if it did not run the while loop at all. Is there anything missing in my code or advice to improve my code?

```
import asyncio
import random
import time


async def retrieve(queue, lock_browser1,lock_browser2,lock_browser3,lock_browser4,lock_browser5): 

    while True:

        item = await queue.get()


        if lock_browser1.locked() is False:
            async with lock_browser1:   
                await asyncio.sleep(random.uniform(3, 5)) #simulate only one browser connect to the website at a time
                print(item)
            break
        else:
            await asyncio.sleep(0)

        if lock_browser2.locked() is False:
            async with lock_browser2:   
                await asyncio.sleep(random.uniform(3, 5)) #simulate only one browser connect to the website at a time
                print(item)
            break
        else:
            await asyncio.sleep(0)
        
        if lock_browser3.locked() is False:
            async with lock_browser3:   
                await asyncio.sleep(random.uniform(3, 5)) #simulate only one browser connect to the website at a time
                print(item)
            break
        else:
            await asyncio.sleep(0)
        
        if lock_browser4.locked() is False:
            async with lock_browser4:   
                await asyncio.sleep(random.uniform(3, 5)) #simulate only one browser connect to the website at a time
                print(item)
            break
        else:
            await asyncio.sleep(0)

        if lock_browser5.locked() is False:
            async with lock_browser5:   
                await asyncio.sleep(random.uniform(3, 5)) #simulate only one browser connect to the website at a time
                print(item)
            break
        else:
            await asyncio.sleep(0)        
        
        if item is None:
            break


async def process(queue,x,y):
    start_value  = 10
    current_value = 0
    stop_value = 15    
    current_value = start_value
    while current_value <= stop_value:
        await queue.put([x,y, current_value])          
        current_value = current_value + 1  
        await asyncio.sleep(0)

    await queue.put(None)


    
    
async def main(x,y):
    
    lock_browser1 = asyncio.Lock()
    lock_browser2 = asyncio.Lock()
    lock_browser3 = asyncio.Lock()
    lock_browser4 = asyncio.Lock()
    lock_browser5 = asyncio.Lock()    
    
    queue = asyncio.Queue()    
    await asyncio.gather(process(queue, x, y),retrieve(queue,lock_browser1,lock_browser2,lock_browser3,lock_browser4,lock_browser5))
  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.perf_counter()
    for x in range(2):   
        for y in range(5):
                asyncio.run(main(x,y))
    end = time.perf_counter()
    duration=end-start
    print(f'Time elapsed:{duration:.2f}s')
```

INCORRECT RESULT:

```
[0, 0, 10]
[0, 1, 10]
[0, 2, 10]
[0, 3, 10]
[0, 4, 10]
[1, 0, 10]
[1, 1, 10]
[1, 2, 10]
[1, 3, 10]
[1, 4, 10]
```

INTEND RESULT:

```
[0, 0, 10]
[0, 0, 11]
[0, 0, 12]
[0, 0, 13]
[0, 0, 14]
[0, 0, 15]
[0, 1, 10]
[0, 1, 11]
[0, 1, 12]
   ...
[1, 4, 13]
[1, 4, 14]
[1, 4, 15]
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the browser locks?

Comment: Is the queue mandatory?

Comment: Is `#simulate only one browser connect to the website at a time` supposed to be `# simulate only one request per browser at a time`?

Comment: @aaron yes, you are correct, it was a typo

Comment: @wwii I try to lock it such that if I pass more than 1 retrieve function inside asyncio.gather , the async processes won’t cram into the same browser but only to the browser that isn’t working

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR - remove the `break` from the if-statements and find another way not to run two or more of them, fix at the end.

The code really does what you tell it to do. Let's break it down into smaller pieces.

#### Part 1 - `if __name__ ...`

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.perf_counter()
    for x in range(2):
        for y in range(5):
            asyncio.run(main(x, y))
    end = time.perf_counter()
    duration = end - start
    print(f'Time elapsed:{duration:.2f}s')
```

We have nested loops, the outer one (`x`) goes from `0-1` and the inner one (`y`) goes from `0-4`, each iteration we call `asyncio.run(main(x, y))`, keep in mind calling `asyncio.run` one after another does not make it run concurrently - it will first call `main(0, 0)` - block everything else until it finishes, then move to the next call (i.e `main(0, 1)`).

#### Part 2 - The `main` function:

Following that, we called `main(0, 0)` and we move to the `main` function:

```py
async def main(x, y):

    lock_browser1 = asyncio.Lock()
    lock_browser2 = asyncio.Lock()
    lock_browser3 = asyncio.Lock()
    lock_browser4 = asyncio.Lock()
    lock_browser5 = asyncio.Lock()

    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    await asyncio.gather(process(queue, x, y),
                         retrieve(queue, lock_browser1, lock_browser2, lock_browser3, lock_browser4, lock_browser5))
```

I will dismiss the locks part - we create a new queue - `queue`. And call `asyncio.gather()` - which in contrast to `asyncio.run` - does run these functions concurrently. Again, dismissing the `retrieve` for now. We call `process`, again, one at a time because our `main` is being called one at a time.

#### Part 3 - The `process` function

```py
async def process(queue, x, y):
    start_value = 10
    stop_value = 15
    current_value = start_value
    while current_value <= stop_value:
        await queue.put([x, y, current_value])
        current_value = current_value + 1
    await queue.put(None)
```

Here we iterate through values `10-15` with our original `x, y` values. We put the list inside the queue - and... that's it probably, nothing more than that.

#### Part 4 - The `retrieve` function

```py
async def retrieve(queue, lock_browser1, lock_browser2, lock_browser3, lock_browser4, lock_browser5):
    while True:

        item = await queue.get()
        if lock_browser1.locked() is False:

            async with lock_browser1:
                await asyncio.sleep(random.uniform(0.2, 0.3))  # simulate only one browser connect to the website at a time
                print(item)
            break
        else:
            await asyncio.sleep(0)
```

I've not added the full function, because it is too long, and it is basically useless - as `lock_browser1` is always `False` - meaning we do enter the first if-statement, and then break from the `while True` - making the other if-else-blocks basically *redundant* (note that).

---

#### Summary:

We "pinch" together two functions: `process` and `retrieve` and run them concurrently, the `process` function is executing a fast `while` loop that increments the last number to the list making it look like: `[0, 0, 10], [0, 0, 11] ...` while `retrieve` gets the elements in the queue, prints the first element, **breaks** from the while-loop and the whole process starts over with a clean fresh queue. So by removing the `break` from the if-else statements it should be alright.

**I know** it was a dig for a small change, I will add a TL;DR for it, but I wanted to point out some things I found important to mention in case you missed them in your code.

#### Fix

I would add a flag that is true if we have entered an if statement, and false otherwise (I've moved the check if `item` is not `None` to the head of the block, so we won't print `None` for no use):

```py
async def retrieve(queue, lock_browser1, lock_browser2, lock_browser3, lock_browser4, lock_browser5):
    while True:
        has_entered_if = False
        item = await queue.get()

        if item is None:
            break

        if lock_browser1.locked() is False and not has_entered_if:
            has_entered_if = True
            async with lock_browser1:
                await asyncio.sleep(random.uniform(3, 5))  # simulate only one browser connect to the website at a time
                print(item)

        else:
            await asyncio.sleep(0)

        if lock_browser2.locked() is False and not has_entered_if:
            has_entered_if = True
            async with lock_browser2:
                await asyncio.sleep(random.uniform(3, 5))  # simulate only one browser connect to the website at a time
                print(item)
        else:
            await asyncio.sleep(0)

        if lock_browser3.locked() is False and not has_entered_if:
            has_entered_if = True
            async with lock_browser3:
                await asyncio.sleep(random.uniform(3, 5))  # simulate only one browser connect to the website at a time
                print(item)
        else:
            await asyncio.sleep(0)

        if lock_browser4.locked() is False and not has_entered_if:
            has_entered_if = True
            async with lock_browser4:
                await asyncio.sleep(random.uniform(3, 5))  # simulate only one browser connect to the website at a time
                print(item)
        else:
            await asyncio.sleep(0)

        if lock_browser5.locked() is False and not has_entered_if:
            async with lock_browser5:
                await asyncio.sleep(random.uniform(3, 5))  # simulate only one browser connect to the website at a time
                print(item)
        else:
            await asyncio.sleep(0)
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 10]
[0, 0, 11]
[0, 0, 12]
[0, 0, 13]
[0, 0, 14]
[0, 0, 15]
[0, 1, 10]
[0, 1, 11]
[0, 1, 12]
...
[1, 4, 10]
[1, 4, 11]
[1, 4, 12]
[1, 4, 13]
[1, 4, 14]
[1, 4, 15]
```

Comment: I tried it and the output was my intended output but the whole process appeared as if running synchronously. My intention is to run the current_value (10-15) concurrently, is that possible? or I have to implement worker number to manage the task at the same time？

Comment: @jguy you are sleeping not between each iteration of the while loop of `process`, but in the `retrieve`, and the whole point of asyncronous functions is that you can do other things while that function does things (i.e. sleeps), but the same function can't do other operations while it's sleeping.

Comment: but the function itself is an async function, I assume each while loop it will have 6 data(current_value=10,11,12,13,14,15) that can run the async retrieve() function asynchronously instead of synchronously or am I missing something?

Comment: @jguy yes and no,yes it is async function, however it is blocked each time we sleep, so it waits 3-5 seconds between each print of the queue

Comment: I try to run it asynchronously by adding a few more retrieve() inside asyncio.gather()function as follow but it stuck after the first while loop? await asyncio.gather(process(queue, x, y),
                         retrieve(queue, lock_browser1, lock_browser2, lock_browser3, lock_browser4, lock_browser5),retrieve(queue, lock_browser1, lock_browser2, lock_browser3, lock_browser4, lock_browser5),retrieve(queue, lock_browser1, lock_browser2, lock_browser3, lock_browser4, lock_browser5))

Comment: "keep in mind calling asyncio.run one after another does not make it run concurrently " This probably could be worded more clearly. `asyncio.run()` does causes *something* to be called concurrently. The problem is that `main(x, y)` **immediately** calls `main()` and then passes the result to `asyncio.run()`. This probably isn't what is desired.

Answer (score 2):

That `retrieve` function allows only one browser (Selenium driver) to run at a time.

A more reasonable implementation, to simulate only one request per browser at a time:

```py
async def retrieve(queue, lock_browser1, lock_browser2, lock_browser3, lock_browser4, lock_browser5):
    async def _retrieve(lock_browser):
        while True:
            async with lock_browser:
                await asyncio.sleep(random.uniform(3, 5))  # simulate only one request per browser at a time
                item = await queue.get()
                if item is None:
                    await queue.put(None)  # allow others to exit
                    break
                print(item)

    await asyncio.gather(
        _retrieve(lock_browser1),
        _retrieve(lock_browser2),
        _retrieve(lock_browser3),
        _retrieve(lock_browser4),
        _retrieve(lock_browser5),
    )
```

The `process` function and a suitable `process_main` function:

```py
async def process(queue, x, y):
    start_value = 10
    stop_value = 15
    current_value = start_value
    while current_value <= stop_value:
        await queue.put([x, y, current_value])
        current_value = current_value + 1
        await asyncio.sleep(0)


async def process_main(queue):
    for x in range(2):
        for y in range(5):
            await process(queue, x, y)
    await queue.put(None)
```

The `main` function should hold the `lock_browser` instances, and the `if __name__ == "__main__":` block should only call the `main` function once:

```py
async def main():
    lock_browser1 = asyncio.Lock()
    lock_browser2 = asyncio.Lock()
    lock_browser3 = asyncio.Lock()
    lock_browser4 = asyncio.Lock()
    lock_browser5 = asyncio.Lock()

    queue = asyncio.Queue()

    await asyncio.gather(
        process_main(queue),
        retrieve(queue, lock_browser1, lock_browser2, lock_browser3, lock_browser4, lock_browser5),
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.perf_counter()
    asyncio.run(main())
    end = time.perf_counter()
    duration = end - start
    print(f'Time elapsed: {duration:.2f}s')
```

This runs in about 53 seconds on my machine.

Comment: I had the impression that each lock was *associated* with a selenium web driver instance. I was trying something similar: calling a retrieve(lock,driver,url) for each *url* without using a queue; using 5 locks, 5 drivers (I wrote a proxy);  so there are multiple retrieve instances being awaited and each of those awaiting a lock. They were executing aasynchronously but there wasn't much if any time savings.

Comment: @wwii Would you share that in a Gist? That sounds interesting to take a look at.

Comment: It was on my computer at work so I had to re-create it. In that process I seemed to have improved it. It is now executing faster than total *retrieval* time. [tmp-async.py](https://gist.github.com/wbwallace/58bd7c0d0f45d153017a66e696a92928)

Answer (score 0):

I also thought that retrieve should only have one webdriver with one url to get (at a time). I was wondering whether the queue was actually necessary, I thought I could *launch* and await a retrieve instance for each url using the locks to limit a driver to one `get` at a time.

I wrote a driver proxy to simulate a non-async blocking method. Running driver.get in an executor was the key to getting this working.

```
import asyncio
import random
import time
from pprint import pprint
from itertools import cycle,product

class Webdriver:
    '''Blocking webdriver proxy.
    '''
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
    def get(self,url):
        snooze = random.uniform(3,5)
        time.sleep(snooze)
        return (f'{self.name}: {url}',round(snooze,3))

# acquire the lock, wait for then return a result
async def retrieve(lock,driver,url):
    await lock.acquire()
    try:
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        result = await loop.run_in_executor(None,driver.get,url)
    finally:
        lock.release()
    return result

async def main():
    # five locks and drivers
    # pair a lock with a driver
    drivers = [(asyncio.Lock(),Webdriver(f'driver{n}')) for n in range(5)]
    drivers = cycle(drivers)

    # fifty urls
    urls = product(range(2),range(5),range(10,15))

    # make fifty tasks, one for each url
    args = zip(drivers,urls)
    tasks = set()
    for (lock,driver),url in args:
        task = asyncio.create_task(retrieve(lock,driver,url))
        tasks.add(task)

    stuff = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    return stuff

if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = time.time()
    result = asyncio.run(main())
    print(f'exc_time:{time.time()-q:.1f}, ntasks:{len(result)}, retrieval_time:{sum(a[-1] for a in result):.1f}')
    result.sort(key=lambda x: x[0][-10:])
#    pprint(result)
```

---

This works and performs pretty well. It distributes the urls *evenly* across the (lock,driver) pairs. I think that it mostly works because the *get* times are all fairly close - if a driver happened to get urls that were quick it would run through them and then not be able to help anymore. If a single url took a looong time it would hold up a driver and the other driver's wouldn't be able to take up the slack. For those two cases multiple drivers pulling from a queue would work better - something along the line of [aaron's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75266606/2823755).